# Need a Ruby gem for Cucumber test automation of a legacy Windows desktop application written in VB 6

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, desktop-application, ui-automation

**The Background**:  Several months ago, my team initially implemented a robust Ruby/Cucumber test automation framework for a client that touches various internal Web applications, APIs and databases.

The client returned and inquired about extending the Ruby/Cucumber framework to include a legacy Windows Desktop application (written in VB 6) that requires validations that already exist in the current framework.

**The Problem**:  After extensive research, I have uncovered several gems that should be somewhat helpful but do not provide all required capabilities. For example, outside of "standard" desktop application functions such as clicking buttons, traversing menus/tables, and filling out forms, dynamic drag-and-drop functionality is one of the more complicated features of the Windows desktop application to be automated.

I have looked into the gems RAutomation, Mohawk, Win32-autogui, and Sikuli/Rukuli and some combination of the above should provide most of the capabilities required.

**The Question**:  Does anyone know of any Ruby gem (or combination of gems) that integrates well with Windows desktop applications?

In an ideal world, I am holding out hope for something like Calabash/Appium for Windows apps.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) can do the job for legacy VB6 app, but it's Python. Though there is [rubypython](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org/) bridge. Maybe too tricky, but if nothing else helps... Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm testing gem 'uia', so far it's meeting the needs.
I made an example with the calculator, go on.

```
#***************************************************
# Test calc.exe
#***************************************************
require 'uia'

#'window'
calc = Uia.find_element title: 'Calculadora'

#Cap a name

btn1 = calc.find(name: '1')

#cap controls def for control_type

btns = calc.find_all(control_type: :buttons)

#btns is array buttons

#cap all child the calc.exe

ctrls = calc.children


#***************************************************
```